# Accessing file paths in excel cells with python

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, pypdf, xlwings

I have a spreadsheet that has the file paths of pdfs in its cells. The file paths are currently hyperlinks and have shortened names like "001", "002" rather than the address.

I am trying to access these file paths in python and attempting to merge them into one pdf file. I am struggling to access the file paths though - all I can return are the numbers 1.0 and 2.0 which are the names of the file path hyperlinks. The code I have so far is below, any reason why this isn't returning the file paths I need? Many thanks!

```
import xlwings as xw
import PyPDF2
import openpyxl


path = r"C:\Users\JCP2\demo\demo.xlsm"
wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
ws = wb["Sheet1"]
print(ws.cell(2, 1).hyperlink.target)`
```

The code I tried is above. I expected it to print a file path such as C::\User....  but instead the output was 1.0 or 2.0 which were the names given to these file paths in the cells.

Comment: Can you provide the demo.xlsm for download? Does it need to have macros or can you make it a xslx as well?

Comment: demo.xlsm is just a blank document with cells A2 containing "001" as a hyperlink to a pdf file saved to a folder on my computer and A3 has "002" similarly with a hyperlink to another pdf. That's it for the moment as I am trying to get this to work before designing the proper workbook. Macros will be needed as I am hoping to have a button to merge these pdfs eventually through python

Comment: Output is correct for me. Sorry. Without the Excel file I can't help

Comment: You don't seem to use PyPDF2.

Comment: Ah yes. Not on this part of it but I'm hoping to merge these two pdfs together with PyPDF2 at some point.....when I can actually access their file paths from the workbook

Comment: I don't believe there have been any issues with Openpyxl and hyperlinks where the cell value would be returned for the hyperlink target, however are you using a late or the latest Openpyxl release? **.hyperlink** does not contain an attribute that would return the cell value. What about Xlwings, what does **print(xw.Range('A2').hyperlink)** return?

Comment: Dear All, many thanks for your help. I have managed to find a solution using xlwings. This seemed to work:

Comment: import xlwings as xw
import PyPDF2
import openpyxl

wbxl=xw.Book('demo.xlsm')
print(wbxl.sheets['Sheet1'].range('C2:C3').value)

Comment: @JonPercival please post what worked as an answer rather than in the comments. You can even accept it to mark this question as answered.

Comment: So you changed your hyperlinks to values in the cell?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I managed to do this was change the hyperlinks to values in each cell.

```
# opens the workbook and gets the file paths.
wbxl = xw.Book('demo.xlsm')
get_links = wbxl.sheets['Sheet1'].range('C2:C5').value

# gets rid of any blank cells in range and makes a list of all the file 
paths called filenames
filenames = []
for file in get_links:
    if file is not None:
         filenames.append(file)
```